# How to pass an array from function to function

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement

So I'm fairly new to programming in general and I am working on a project where I have to create a couple of functions.
Everything is fine with the first function but I can't figure out how to pass the values from the first function to the second function
I know that I need to use some pointers to solve the problem but I was just wondering if there was an easier way until i get the hang of using pointers.
Thanks in advance!

Here's my messy code

```
     #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define START_SIZE 2

int number_of_branches=0;
typedef struct
           {
              int Month_num[12];
              double sales[12];
              bool active;
           }Branch;
double function_one(void);
double function_two(void);
double function_three(void);
void function_four(void);



int main()
{
    int User_Selection;
    do
    {
    printf("1. Enter sales data.\n2. Add a record for a new branch.\n3. Delete record of an existing branch.\n4. Calculate total sales.\n5. Calculate percentage share of each branch.\n6. Determine the month of peak sales.\n7. Display sales of a specific month.\n8. Display sales of a specific branch.\n0. Done\n");
    scanf("%i",&User_Selection);

    switch (User_Selection)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        printf("Thankyou for your time :)\n");
        break;
    }

    case 1:
    {
        function_one();
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        function_two();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        function_three();
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        function_four();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid input :)\n");
        break;
    }
    }
    }
    while(User_Selection!=0);
}


double function_one(void)
{
    //FILE *file = fopen("Sales.csv","a");
    printf("Ender number of branches: ");
    scanf("%d",&number_of_branches);
    printf("\n");
        Branch Branches[number_of_branches];
        RecPointer r;
        r = (RecPointer)malloc(sizeof(Rec));
        //printf("%d",number_of_branches);
        for(int b=0; b<number_of_branches; b++)
        {
            printf("Sales for branch %d: \n",(b+1));
            for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
            {
                printf("Sales for month %d: ",(x+1));
                scanf("%lf",&Branches[b].sales[x]);
                //printf("\n%lf\n",Branches[b].sales[x]);
                //fprintf(file, "%d,%.2lf\n",x,Branches[b].sales[x]);
                //fprintf(file,"\n");
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
     //fclose(file);
     printf("Branch\\Month:\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\n");
     for(int b=0; b<number_of_branches; b++)
        {
            printf("Branch %d:\t",(b+1));
            for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
            {
                printf("%.2lf\t",(Branches[b].sales[x]));

            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
        Branch * Branchplace = (Branch *) malloc(sizeof(Branch));

}

double function_two(void)
{
    Branch Branches[number_of_branches++];
    printf("Sales for the new branch number %d\n",(number_of_branches));
    for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
{
                printf("Sales for month %d: ",(x+1));
                scanf("%lf",&Branches[number_of_branches].sales[x]);
                //printf("\n%d\n",x);
}
     printf("\n");
     printf("Branch\\Month:\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\n");
     for(int b=0; b<number_of_branches; b++)
        {
            printf("Branch %d:\t",(b+1));
            for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
            {
                printf("%.2lf\t",(Branches[b].sales[x]));
                //printf("\n%lf\n",Branches[b].sales[x]);
                //fprintf(file, "%d,%lf",x,Branches[b].sales[x]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
         return 0;

}

double function_three(void)
{
    Branch Branches[number_of_branches];
    int deleted_branch;
    printf("Which branch do you want to delete?\n");
    scanf("%d",&deleted_branch);
    Branches[deleted_branch].active=false;
    printf("Deleted branch %d\n",deleted_branch);
    return 0;
}

void function_four(void)
{
Branch Branches[number_of_branches];

    for(int n=0;n<number_of_branches;n++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
        printf("%.lf\n",Branches[n].sales[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: to which function you want to pass, in your code, give me the function name

Comment: `typedef struct { ... } Branch;` is an idiom from C, I'd recommend just writing `struct Branch { ... };` in C++.  I also recommend `const int START_SIZE = 2;` as opposed to `#define START_SIZE 2`.  Roughly, the first says *START_SIZE should refer to the constant integer value 2* while the macro says *everywhere I write START_SIZE should be replaced with the token 2.*  One is semantic, and the compiler will help you in an intuitive way, the other is lexical, and while appropriate in some cases, is probably not what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is easy to pass an array, no need for pointer

```
  void myfunction(int array[]) {
       /**  your code here **/
      array[0] = 25;
  }

  void main() {
      int arr[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};
      int i;
      myfunction(arr);
      for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
      }
  }
```

Output

```
  25
  2
  4
  5
```

As you can see the value 25 is printing which is actually modified inside the function